# Is there a way to simplify or reuse functions parameters in typesscript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm confused about the way to simplify the parameters of function in TypeScript.

I have the lines of code just like the below.

```
export type RequestGraphqlServer = (
  queryType: "query" | "mutation",
  operationName: string,
  requestData: string,
  variables?: object | null,
  options?: IGraphqlQueryOptions
) => IResponseType;

export type UseQuery = (
  operationName: string,
  requestData: string,
  variables?: object | null,
  options?: IGraphqlQueryOptions
) => ReturnType<RequestGraphqlServer>;

export type UseMutation = (
  operationName: string,
  requestData: string,
  variables?: object | null,
  options?: IGraphqlQueryOptions
) => ReturnType<RequestGraphqlServer>;
```

I've tried some generic types like `Parameters` and `Omit`, but I couldn't get it to work. How can I simplify and reuse the function parameters?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "simplify and reuse the function parameters"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you want to simplify the parameters. However here is how to reuse them:

```
export type RequestGraphqlServer = (queryType: 'query' | 'mutation', operationName: string, requestData: string, variables?: object | null, options?: IGraphqlQueryOptions) => IResponseType;

type GraphqlSharedParameters<T=RequestGraphqlServer> = T extends ((queryType: 'query' | 'mutation', ...args: infer U) => IResponseType) ? U : never

export type UseQuery = (...args: GraphqlSharedParameters) => ReturnType<RequestGraphqlServer>;
export type UseMutation = (...args: GraphqlSharedParameters) => ReturnType<RequestGraphqlServer>;
```

However, if `RequestGraphqlServer` is not automatically generated, I would recommend creating the shared type first and reusing it in all other type definitions, like this:

```
export type GraphqlSharedParameters = [operationName: string, requestData: string, variables?: object | null, options?: IGraphqlQueryOptions];

export type RequestGraphqlServer = (queryType: 'query' | 'mutation', ...args: GraphqlSharedParameters) => IResponseType;

export type UseQuery = (...args: GraphqlSharedParameters) => ReturnType<RequestGraphqlServer>;
export type UseMutation = (...args: GraphqlSharedParameters) => ReturnType<RequestGraphqlServer>;
```

Comment: At first, thanks for your helping, but I am confused because I usethe the code lines you provided. But I got the errors like below for examples:

TS2322: Type '(name: string, operation: any, requestData: any, variables: any, options: any) => IResponseType' is not assignable to type 'UseQuery'.

TS7006: Parameter 'operation' implicitly has an 'any' type.

 Actually, I had try some generic just like you did yesterday, I got the same ts errors.
 I don't know how to solve this problem. Is my typescript version is not compatiable with this generics?

My typescript version 4.9.5.

Comment: First, sorry for the late reply. From your error message, it seems your function takes a string as its first argument, so you would need the following type definition: `export type UseQuery = (name: string, ...args: GraphqlSharedParameters) => ReturnType<RequestGraphqlServer>`
I am testing the types with 4.9.5 as well, so it should be working on your side too.